# Linux script execute command failed when there is a dot in the variable value

Tags: linux, git, shell

This is what I wrote in linux shell.

```
read RELEASE_BRANCH

git checkout -b $RELEASE_BRANCH
```

When I input something with a dot, the execution of git checkout -b failed. 
For example, RELEASE_BRANCH=Release1.03

Can someone pls help?

Comment: Works for me. What is the error message?

Comment: Try double quoting git checkout -b "$RELEASE_BRANCH"

Comment: That will fix problems with spaces in the name. dots shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Unless the script has earlier put `.` into `$IFS`.

Comment: But you should generally quote variables, unless you specifically need it to be split into words.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by your [other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40141583/1256452), this is because you set `IFS=.` earlier.

As [Charles Duffy wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141583/execution-order-in-shell-script#comment67554114_40141583), don't do that (don't leave bogus `IFS` values set after a `read`).

Answer (score 0):

So adding a double quote around the variable solve the problem.